# About MPAndroidChart XAxis Label

Tags: mpandroidchart, x-axis

My chart lineDataSet entry maybe has more than seven, but the xAxis Labels only have seven at most. I have setting: `xAxis.setLabelCount(7, true)`，force is true. 
The X-axis label type is `Date`, corresponding to the Y-axis data. Although the labels are evenly divided on the X-axis, they cannot be aligned with the Y-axis data. Unless force is not set, my requirement is that the X-axis only displays up to 7 dates.

Is there a way to ensure that labels can be aligned when multiple data is based on demand (see screenshot). LineDateSet has nine entries. How can I align the  X-axis labels?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, can be maybe provide some code and examples like a screenshot? I don't understand the question.

Comment: thank，see screenshot，lineDateSet have nine entry,how to align the  X-axis lable

Comment: what is your dataset?